# etcd3 docker persist discovery information

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, etcd, etcd3

I want to deploy an ETC cluster with 3 nodes with Docker.
So I use a dicovery url for that purpose.
The problem Im having is that when I delete a etcd container, and start a new one, then it cannot rejoin to the cluster.
Docker log says:
member "XXX" has previously registered with discovery service token (https://discovery.etcd.io/yyyy)
But etcd could not find valid cluster configuration in the given data dir (/data).

I am using volume for folder /data and /waldir
Also using --net=host so it is using the same host IP always.

But why can't the new container re-join to the cluster?
Where the cluster information is saved inside the container?

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.